# About Homeomorphism and Intermediate value property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, connectedness

let $h\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function with intermediate value property and let $g\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a homeomorphism. Then $h\circ g$ has the intermediate value property.

**My attempt**: let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$ and $(h\circ g)(a)<y<(h\circ g)(b). $ We need to find an $x\in (a,b)$ such that $(h\circ g)(x)=y.$ Now,  note that $$h(g(a))<y<h(g(b))\tag{1}.$$ Also, notice that $g$ is a homeomorphism so it is strictly  increasing or strictly decreasing.

**Case I:** If $g$ is strictly increasing, then $g(a)<g(b)$. Since $h$ has intermediate value property. So, by $(1)$, there exists an $z\in(g(a),g(b))$ such that $h(z)=y.$ Since $g$ is a homeomorphism then there exists an $x\in (a,b)$ such that $g(x)=z.$ Then, $(h\circ g)(x)=y.$

**Case II:** If $g$ is strictly decreasing, then $g(a)>g(b).$ Since $h$ has intermediate value property. So, by $(1)$, there exists an $r\in(g(b),g(a))$ such that $h(r)=y.$  Since $g$ is a homeomorphism then there exists an $x\in (a,b)$ such that $g(x)=r.$ Then, $(h\circ g)(x)=y.$

This property is true but I am not sure if my proof has a gap or incorrect step.  Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: As an alternative approach: the intermediate value property can be restated as image of connected subset is connected. And thus if two functions satisfy this then so does their composition. It is quite straight forward.

Comment: @freakish, yes, this is correct. Did you check what if it is correct or not

Comment: @Brian M. Scott, Did you have chance to check my short argument?